# How can use JS to take a screenshot of a Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have looked into html2canvas and attempted to follow this [blog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3dJn.png) but I am coming up with error: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3dJn.png): https://www.sfdcblogs.com/post/create-screenshot-from-div-in-lwc

How can I overcome this error or what approach can I take to be able to take a screen shot of a particular  or LWC?

[image: Error]